# Linking multiple .MD files in Stash, how to?

Tags: markdown, bitbucket-server

Given the Readme.MD file, i'd like to break it down by sections into multiple .MD files.

To mu knowledge Attlassian Stash does not support the split. Is there a plugin you've tried and liked?

Comment: Hi. Stash developer here. I can confirm Stash doesn't support this feature yet (and I haven't seen a plugin). So are you looking for a basic Wiki style functionality? That is to say a way to link between markdown pages? Vaguely related:https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/stash-markdown-viewer-plugin

Answer (score 2):

If the files are in the same directory (say `Extra.md`) then you can use the markdown:

```
[Extra information](Extra.md)
```

Stash renders the markdown in the "source" view, so you should get the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin may do what you need

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.pirateninjaunicorn.stash.readme-parser

We have a private stash repository and it already seems to be installed as I was able to do something like...

```
[docs/README_docs.md](Docs)
```

And link to a markdown file **README_docs.md** in ./docs

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2017 I am able to link to other files in the repository using

```
[Test Doc](docs/Readme_test.md)
```

Hope this helps someone.